# PHP Continuous read from UDP socket

Tags: php, sockets, firefox, networking, udp

I currently have some PHP code that can read a UDP packet at the time of the web page refresh. It is being sent from a C++ program, and it's continuously sending over the network. I need my PHP code to continuously read and update the web page for each UDP packet received.

Firefox never loads the page with my current code and the only way I can see a packet is to remove the `while(true)` have it only print one packet.

```
<?php

$data = '';

if($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)
{
     socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
     if(socket_bind($socket, "0.0.0.0", 3030))
     {
          while(true)
          {
               $data = socket_read($socket, 512);
               ob_flush();
          }
      }
}

?>
```

Then I'm printing the data to a span to check `<span><?php echo $data; ?></span>`

How do I make it so that I can have a continuous loop reading UDP packets but also be able to have FireFox actually load the webpage? It gets stuck with the message "Waiting on 0.0.0.0" in the bottom left corner message box.

Comment: Look into using Ajax or web sockets for something like this.

Comment: @Dave I tried websockets but could not get FireFox to be able to create sockets due to SELinux constraints.

Comment: are you sure you output $data before ob_flush ? your code does not show it. Also disable any buffering - https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2016/streaming-php-disabling-output-buffering-php-apache-nginx-and-varnish